# Web setup problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, deployment, installation

I need to package my ASP.NET Silverlight web site to a single MSI file.
But when creating web setup project, it can't install on iis version greater than 6. On greater versions it only installs when 'IIS 6 compatibility mode' is enabled on server. How can i make my setup project, so it installs correctly? 
PS I don't have admin rights on server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are installing to IIS7+, I'd suggestion using [Web Deploy](http://www.iis.net/download/webdeploy). It simplifies IIS deployment and is now the recommended way to deploy to IIS7 or above. Also, there is good integration with Visual Studio 2010 as well as both MMC and PowerShell integration with IIS.